# 'VNCEnv' object has no attribute 'remote_manager' when running OpenAI universe example

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-gym

When I try to run the following example code from [here](https://openai.com/blog/universe/), Python is unable to find the `remote_manager` attribute. I have all required packages installed and the [OpenAI gym examples](https://gym.openai.com/docs) appear to work as they should.

I run Python 3.5 under Linux Mint 18, and I got OpenAI gym and universe from the pip repositories.

```
import gym
import universe # register Universe environments into Gym

env = gym.make('flashgames.DuskDrive-v0') # any Universe environment ID here
observation_n = env.reset()

while True:
  # agent which presses the Up arrow 60 times per second
  action_n = [[('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True)] for _ in observation_n]
  observation_n, reward_n, done_n, info = env.step(action_n)
  env.render()
```

The full stacktrace is

```
[2017-01-25 14:04:05,416] Making new env: flashgames.DuskDrive-v0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mark/projects/development-playground/src/utils/openai_experiments.py", line 5, in <module>
observation_n = env.reset()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gym/core.py", line 123, in reset
observation = self._reset()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/universe/wrappers/timer.py", line 15, in _reset
return self.env.reset()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gym/core.py", line 123, in reset
observation = self._reset()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/universe/wrappers/render.py", line 25, in _reset
observation_n = self.env.reset()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gym/core.py", line 123, in reset
observation = self._reset()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/universe/wrappers/throttle.py", line 42, in _reset
observation = self.env.reset()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gym/core.py", line 123, in reset
observation = self._reset()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/universe/envs/vnc_env.py", line 331, in _reset
self._handle_connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/universe/envs/vnc_env.py", line 498, in _handle_connect
for remote in self.remote_manager.pop(n=n):
AttributeError: 'VNCEnv' object has no attribute 'remote_manager'
```

Comment: What does `pip freeze` give you in the venv?

Comment: the output of `pip3 freeze` is here: http://pastebin.com/i3G6sLD5

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to call env.configure()

```
env = gym.make('flashgames.DuskDrive-v0')
env.configure(remotes=1)
observation_n = env.reset()
```